# What is the effect of soap on a blister?

Tags: dermatology, hygiene, hand

Assume that you have a blister on a finger. It's open. Is there a problem if you wash your hands with soap (for instance liquid soap in a public toilet)? What could be the effect of soap on a blister?

For instance, will it get irritated? Can it produce a liquid?

Comment: I think it is better to wash than not

Comment: I can see you've asked this same question in http://www.sciencerr.com/question/what-is-the-effect-of-soap-on-a-blister/

Comment: @Prince Thanks, I did not put it there. It seems that they have copied more questions from SE. I will report this to SE.